# what is actual difference between NSString and NSMutableString in objective C with the help of example?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablestring

what is actual difference between NSString and NSMutable String in Objective-C?
I have searched a lot but not getting any answer..I understand that NSString is Immutable object and NSMutableString is Mutable object but I want to understand the difference between them with the help of an example..Please help me..

now question has solved..

Comment: possible duplicate of [the documentation](http:///developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Immutable String.....

```
NSString *str1 = @"Hello Testing";
NSString *str2 = str1;
```

replace  the  second  string

```
str2 = @"Hello hehehe";
```

And  list  their  current  values

```
NSLog(@"str1 = %@, str2 = %@", str1, str2);
//logs as below
//str1 = Hello Testing, str2 = Hello hehehe
```

Mutable strings

Setup  two  variables  to  point  to  the  same  string

```
NSMutableString * str1 = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Hello Testing"];
NSMutableString * str2 = str1;
```

Replace  the  second  string

```
[str2 setString:@"Hello ikilimnik"];
```

//  And  list  their  current  values

```
NSLog(@"str1 = %@, str2 = %@", str1, str2);
//logs as below
//str1 = Hello ikilimnik, str2 = Hello ikilimnik
```

Notice when you use the immutable string class that the only way to `replace` a string is to create a new string and update your variable `str2` to point to it.

This however doesn't affect what str1 is pointing to, so it will still reference the original string.

In the `NSMutableString` example, we don't create a second string, but instead alter the contents of 
the existing `Hello Testing` string. Since both variables continue to point to the same string object, they will both report the new value in the call to `NSLog`.

It is important to differentiate between a pointer variable and the actual object it points to. 
A `NSString` object is immutable, but that doesn't stop you from changing the value of a variable which points to a string.

Comment: For the immutable: why doesn't str2 become immutable right after str2=str1?

How is it that it can still get a new value of "Hello hehehe"?

Answer (score -1):

In Objective C, two types of string Objects are there one is mutable and Immutable.

To create an immutable string we use `NSString` and to create a mutable string we  use `NSMutableString`.

If we are creating a string object using `NSString`, it is an immutable string object. This means the string cannot subsequently be modified in any way. (although any NSString pointer can be reassigned to a new NSString object.)

```
 NSString *string1 = @"immutable String";
```

For Mutable strings, we use `NSMutableString`, which is a subclass of `NSString`.

To assign a mutable string object:

```
NSMutableString *string2 = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Mutable String"];
```

or

```
NSMutableString *string2 = [NSMutableString stringWithString: string1]; // string1 is a NSString(immutable)
```

Comment: Downvoted: Tried editing this for you to clarify the language, but I'd suggest talking about the use-case for immutable vs mutable strings.  That seems to be the way to uncover the _actual_ differences, instead of merely the _syntactic_ initialization differences.  The accepted answer does a good job. Better luck next time!